# Oracle Forms 6I Navigating to Cursor nth Record

Tags: plsql, cursor, oracleforms

i have an application i have several blocks they are not database blocks. However i am populating it with records from a Cursor. I have a procedure that loops through the cursor records and displays it on the form.

I want to be able to display the nth record in this cursor in a form how can i achieve this. This would be coded behing the next record button on the form.

```
Procedure Get_All_Records IS 
Cursor MyRecords IS 

Select 1,2,3,4,5
from mytable

Begin

FOR eachRecord In MyRecords LOOP
  field1 := eachRecord.1;
  field2 := eachRecord.2;
  field3 := eachRecord.3;
  field4 := eachRecord.4;
  field5 := eachRecord.5;

END LOOP;


End;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Procedure Get_All_Records IS

Cursor MyRecords IS 
    Select 1,2,3,4,5
    from mytable;

rowCont number := 0;
```

Begin

```
FOR eachRecord In MyRecords LOOP

  rowCont := rowCont + 1;

  if rowCont = n then    -- n is you nth record

      field1 := eachRecord.1;
      field2 := eachRecord.2;
      field3 := eachRecord.3;
      field4 := eachRecord.4;
      field5 := eachRecord.5;

  end if;

END LOOP;
```

End;

This might help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should fill your block with all the records of your query, just like a database block would. You can use `create_record` to add records to your block. After you've done that you can use the built-ins like `next_record`, `previous_record`, `go_record`, etc.

Comment: I fill the block with the records form the cursor but the block are not bind to any tables. The application has several blocks and one view so data entry is difficult to do, when u move form one block to the next you get a 'Do you want to save changes' message and this cannot be suppressed. My only option was to build the entire application manually. So create_record and next_record will not work because the block is not based on any table.

Comment: It is possible to work around the 'Do you want to save changes' by posting the changes when you moving out of an database block with changes. The posting are writing the changes to the database but not committing them so they can still be roll backed. Little bit tricky to get to work but I have found this very useful. The posting is done with the POST builtin.

Comment: create_record, next_record, etc. all work fine with non-database blocks. It does sound, however, that you tried database blocks but gave up when you ran into problems. If so, I suggest going back to the database blocks, so you can benefit from the functionality Oracle Forms provides. The message you were getting can be dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

You can populate a multi record none database block like this;

```
First_Record;
FOR eachRecord In MyRecords LOOP
  field1 := eachRecord.1;
  field2 := eachRecord.2;
  field3 := eachRecord.3;
  field4 := eachRecord.4;
  field5 := eachRecord.5;

  Next_Record;
END LOOP;
```

And yes the First_Record and Next_Record is working fine with none database blocks.

Comment: The application odes not use a multi-record block its a form layout with several single blocks

Comment: @dev_darin It doesn't matter, you would still want to fill your blocks with all records and have your form view dislay the current record of each one, which Forms is built to do. It sounds like you're reinventing the wheel for a lot of stuff that Forms will do for you.

Comment: @GriffeyDog i am using forms 6i yes i was doing it as a database block however the application has several tables and that results in several blocks each block was tied to a table however when i am in add mode or query mode once i leave one block its asking me to save changes. I tried to surpess the message but nothing worked. The research i did everyone said i would have to either do a commit on the block before i leave it or clear it. That was not possible with the application since its a customer registration form. If you have any solution to this problem please post it.

Comment: @GriffeyDog what i am doing is i removed all the blocks as database items and now i am doing every thing manually. Custom form states and using global variables to store data.

Comment: @dev_darin I must admit that I have to agree with GriffeyDog that most likely your problem is solvable with database blocks. But if you really need to use a none database block you could populate it with all records and then use Previous_Record and Next_Record to navigate between the records. Please notice that even if you only display one record at a time then you can still have multiple records!

Comment: @DJPeter then why does'nt next_record and previous_record work for me when i place the code under buttons. For it to work i have to declare the cursor and loop or fetch through it using next_record and previous record in that way. In the end i have cursors declared for each navigation button

Comment: @dev_darin Naturally for the Next_Record/Previous_Record to work you need to have the cursor in that block. Can it be that you have the buttons in another block? If so then first use Go_Block to navigate to the block where you have the data and then use the builtins. Do also please make sure that the block you are using is not a single record data block (block property 'Single Record').

Comment: @DJPeter yes my buttons are in a different block now this makes sense. hey thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I know I have given an answer before with regard to a cursor in form developer.
I am sorry for my previous answer, but let me give a quick example that might
illustrate on it can be done....

`form fields:
:user_code
:user_name`

In form developer, we will make a button and use a trigger when button pressed to activate the cursor code....

**Lets look at the cursor code in the button**

```
declare
  cursor code_name is
  select user_code, user_name from users;
 begin
   open code_name;
   loop
     fetch code_name into :user_code, :user_name;
     next_record;
     exit when code_name%NOTFOUND;
   end loop;
   close code_name;
 end
```

**Lets view another code that can execute the cursor using the for loop**

```
declare 
cursor code_name is 
select user_code, user_name from users;
begin 
  for sel_code_name in code_name
 loop   
:user_code :=sel_code_name.user_code;   
:user_name := sel_code_name.user_name;
next_record;
end loop;
end;
```

I hope this example is clear enough for those who want to know how to make the
cursor code work... By the way, this is called explicit cursor, and usually;
explicit cursor is user defined, whereas implicit cursor is automatically
done by the database.

Best of luck

Comment: Where is your previous answer? why not just edit that one to add the example?